# ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle-apex

Errors:

```
ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded
ORA-00036: maximum number of recursive SQL levels (50) exceeded
ORA-06512: at "SYS.STANDARD", line 180
ORA-06512: at "ETRACKER.R_TRACKER_TRI", line 7
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ETRACKER.R_TRACKER_TRI'
ORA-06512: at "ETRACKER.R_TRACKER_TRI", line 24
ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ETRACKER.R_TRACKER_TRI'
ORA-06512: at "ETRACKER.R_TRACKER_TRI", line 24 ORA-04088: error during execution of trigger 'ETRACKER.R_TRACK
```

Trigger code:

```
create or replace TRIGGER  R_TRACKER_TRI
   before insert on R_TRACKER
   for each row
   declare
   v_number varchar2(15);
   begin
      if inserting then 
         :NEW.PROJECT_ID := 1;--PROJECT_ID(1);
         :NEW.PRO_CREATED := LOCALTIMESTAMP;
         :NEW.PRO_CREATED_BY := nvl(v('APP_USER'),USER);

         IF :NEW.RECRUITMENT_TYPE= 'New' THEN
            SELECT ('NEW/'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YY') || '/' || (NVL(MAX(SUBSTRB(PROJECT_ID,8)),10000)+1)) into v_number 
            FROM R_TRACKER
            WHERE SUBSTRB(PROJECT_ID,1,3) = 'NEW';

            :NEW.PROJECT_ID := v_number;
         elsif :NEW.RECRUITMENT_TYPE= 'Replacement' THEN
            SELECT ('REP/'||TO_CHAR(SYSDATE,'YY') || '/' || (NVL(MAX(SUBSTRB(PROJECT_ID,8)),10000)+1)) into v_number 
            FROM R_TRACKER
            WHERE SUBSTRB(PROJECT_ID,1,3) = 'REP';

            :NEW.PROJECT_ID := v_number;      
         end if;

      INSERT INTO R_TRACKER (
         PROJECT_ID,
         PRO_LOC,
         DESIGNATION,
         NO_OF_POSITION,
```

Comment: Why are you inserting a new row into the table the trigger is against? What values are you using for that insert - the `:new` pseudorecord fields? (You also don't need your `v_number` variable, you can select directly into the `:new.project_id` field; you don't *need* two queries for new/replacement, and it would be much better to use sequences than getting the current max ID + 1).

Comment: Formatted error stack for readability.

Answer (score 0):

Because your trigger is recursive trigger. You can read [this article](http://www.dba-oracle.com/t_ora_00036.htm)

Answer (score 0):

Your trigger is going into a infinite loop because

- you have fired a row level insert trigger on R_TRACKER and
- you are doing a insert into same table R_Tracker

Can you send the complete trigger code?